# ActiveStorage and obtaining the GCS URL for other Google Cloud Services?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, rails-activestorage

ActiveStorage by default uses signed URLs in order to render the objects to the views in Ruby on Rails.

However, if I want to use services like Video Intelligence API that use the input of the file already stored in a Google Cloud Bucket, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/how-to) is telling me to use the GCS URL that starts with gs://.

I'm currently not able to find how ot obtain this type of URL from the Rails side that uses ActiveStorage.

Answer (score 1):

So I went to the Cloud Console, and then to the Google Cloud Storage service.  From there I opened my Bucket and looked at the files inside.  the file names all looked similar to UUIDs without file extensions.

So, I went to my Rails Console and ran a query on the ActiveStorage::Blob table for all records with a content_type of "video/mp4" to see all the attributes.  It wasn't the id value but then I saw the key attribute and found that the key matched the corresponding filename on the bucket.

So, assuming we are in the video model where it has has_one_attached :original_upload.  We can use the following convention to derive the gs URL:

```
input_url: "gs://[BUCKET NAME]/#{self.original_upload.blob.key}"
```